# How to get wifi configured networks with wifi turned off in android?

Tags: android, wifi

How to get wifi configured networks with wifi turned off in android?
In case this is not possible, Can I turn on wifi but disable the automatic connection to known networks?

Comment: did you find the way to list the configured networks (Wifi) with WIFI ON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search on the net I found that this is not possible :(